# Simpler way to write x == 1 && y == 1 && z == 1 in Kotlin?

Tags: android-studio, kotlin

I was wondering if there is a simpler or shorter way to write repetitive conditions like x == 1 && y == 1 && z == 1?

Comment: Have you looked at the `when` expression? https://kotlinlang.org/docs/control-flow.html#when-expression

Comment: If it is explicitly about all variables being 1, then _x * y * z == 1_ will do.

Comment: @lukas.j you should be careful with such "optimisations", because -1 * -1 * 1 == 1, so this could lead to wrong behaviour.

Comment: @Simulant: good catch – didn't think of that.

Comment: @gator I have but I am not sure how to implement it using when. Do you have a working example?

Answer (score 3):

You could consider using [predicates using `all`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.sequences/all.html). For example:

```kotlin
listOf(x, y, z).all {it == 1}
```

This will return `true` when `x==1`, `y==1`, and `z==1`.

If the goal is to *shorten* what you want, there's not much legroom as your boolean expression is already very concise. Some of the other answers have illustrated how to make what you want more *readable*, however.

Comment: Thanks for the input. Yeah, for readability purposes, I could try out the solutions provided. I was actually hoping to see if there is a way to make the code shorter than it is without repetition, like maybe an inbuilt shortcut or something =)

Comment: @sammy then not really. My `listOf` solution is longer than the expression you need to shorten, but if you had a longer expression (instead of three equalities, maybe five or more), it would be shorter. As I said, there's no way to really shorten it as it's already very concise.

Answer (score 3):

When it is (exactly) repeated code, you should consider to extract the statement into a method and give a meaningfull name, which you know from the context where it is used. This makes the requirement (reading the code) easier to understand, at the point where it is used. And it makes it also easier to spot the it is always the same condition.

```
if (conditionName(x, y, z)) {

}

fun boolean conditionName(int x, int y, int z) {
    return x == 1 && y == 1 && z == 1;
}
```

I cannot think of a shorter statement for the condition, but a method extraction will improve your code readability, which should be your overall goal.

Comment: Thanks, but I am actually looking for a shorter way to write that.

Answer (score 2):

You can make a convenience function for this kind of repeated code (or if you just need it to be more readable, or safer to edit):

```
fun <T> T.allEqual(vararg items: T) = items.all { it == this }

// or you could make the receiver the first parameter instead, this is just
// more explicit about which item is the value being compared against
1.allEqual(x, y, z)
```

But no, there isn't any other shorthand built into the language as far as I'm aware - conditions like `x == 1` chained with boolean operators are about as simple as it can get! If you want to check multiple things without repeating yourself, `any` and `all` make that easy, while being flexible for all kinds of situations, and allowing the user to put together the functionality they need with those more general functions.

If you specifically want a version of `all` that does a simple comparison to a single value, and doesn't require creating an iterable like `listOf`, you have to write your own with those tools (which is basically what I've done). It's up to you if you think it's worth it!

Answer (score 0):

```
val x = 1
val y = 1
var z = 1

println("$x$y$z" == "111")   // prints 'true'

z = 2

println("$x$y$z" == "111")   // prints 'false'
```

Answer (score 0):

If it makes sense you could hold those variables in a class

```
data class XYZ(
  val x: Int,
  val y: Int,
  val z: Int)
```

And compare your instance with `XYZ(1, 1, 1)`;

Or if it's just those three variables, you could write

```
if (Triple(x, y, z) == Triple(1, 1, 1))
```